# Qsort and incompatible comparator function - C++

Tags: c++, qsort

I have a struct `subPolygon` and a vector of pointers to that struct. I'm trying to use `qsort` on the vector but the comparator function is shown as incompatible. What am I doing wrong?

```
int cmpFunc(const void *p, const void *q) {
    struct subPolygon* p1 = *((struct subPolygon**)p);
    struct subPolygon* p2 = *((struct subPolygon**)q);
    int s1 = p1->size;
    int s2 = p2->size;
    if (s1-s2 < 0 ) return -1;
    if (s1 == s2) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Here's the declaration of the vector:

```
vector<subPolygon*> subPolygons;
```

The `qsort` call:

```
qsort(&subPolygons[0], subPolygons.size(), sizeof(struct subPolygon*),cmpFunc);
```

Edit: 
It seems the problem was an extra error:
`cmpFunc: non-standard synatx; use & to create pointer to a member "` 
My comparator function was a member of a class. Qsort was called from a member of that class. Making my comparator function static solved the problem.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `qsort` in C++ to begin with?

Comment: I'm having a course on computational geometry and we are not focusing so much on learning C++ as we only need basic stuff. I just needed a sorting and I remembered the qsort function from what I've done in my java course.

Comment: I would not consider legacy-compatibility features like `qsort` part of "the basic stuff". And guessing C++ behavior based on Java experience has *severe* limitations at least. Anyway, the normal sorting function in C++ is [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), check it out.

Comment: What error do you get? [It seems to work fine for me](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5dZGinybvn02UPOH)...

Comment: @MaxLanghof It seems I'm getting an extra error  " cmpFunc: non-standard synatx; use & to create pointer to a member "

Comment: @JohnKatsantas: That belongs in the question, not the comments below the question. Also, duplicate - search for the error message next time. (That;s why it belongs in the question)

Comment: @MSalters I didn't notice that error until now. I always search first. I had already lost half an hour searching before sending here. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Not necessary; that's just another flag in the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you should really do:

```
bool compare(const subPolygon *p1, const subPolygon *p2)
{
    int s1 = p1->size;
    int s2 = p2->size;
    return (s1-s2 < 0);
    // Or just: return p1->size < p2->size;
}

std::sort(subPolygons.begin(), subPolygons.end(), compare);
```

Comment: IMHO what OP should really do is: `std::sort(subPolygons.begin(), subPolygons.end(), [](const subPolygon* p1, const subPolygon* p2) { return p1->size < p2->size; });`

Comment: I considered that, but I did not want to throw lambdas at a C++ novice. But yes, the lamdba solution is generally nicer (unless you have a lot of sorting calls, then the lambda repetition would start smelling).

Comment: @MaxLanghof Thanks for your understanding. I tried this and I'm still getting that use "& to create a pointer to member" error.

Comment: Then please provide a more complete example, because [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TXv9VbZjL2Et6aBT) works for me.

Comment: @JohnKatsantas `compare` should not be a member of any class

Comment: @Caleth: Nothing wrong with a `static` member. The problem is that `compare` as implemented would take _three_ arguments: it would need to be called as `a.compare(b,c)`. `qsort` expects something that can be called as `compare(a,b)`, and `&subPolygon::compare` could qualify.

Comment: It is indeed a member of a class in my code. However, the struct is a member of that class and the comparator function won't recognise it unless I make it a member of the class. Sorry for the trouble, I can work it from here.

Comment: `(s1-s2 < 0)` this seems pointless and potentially dangerous if `s2` is negative (as it risks UB in the form of overflow).  Why not just do `s1 < s2`?

Comment: @Yakk Because I wanted to keep the code similar enough to the OP. There are much more pressing issues in his code than worrying about overflow. And yes, `s1 < s2` is generally more understandable than the subtraction, but this in-between step makes the equivalence of the two obvious, which is why I thought it optimal for the purpose here (since the question is a duplicate anyway).